# How would I grab all articles and order by number of comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I grab only articles with comments that were created 20 minutes ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594249/how-would-i-grab-only-articles-with-comments-that-were-created-20-minutes-ago)

Using mongodb and mongoid. How would one grab all articles and order by number of comments?

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :article
end
```

Comment: Add a counter cache (perhaps [this one](https://github.com/jah2488/mongoid-magic-counter-cache)) and make it easy on yourself?

Comment: I thought of using a counter cache, but just curious to see if there is another way by means of counting the comments

Comment: Nope, no other good way. You must use a counter cache if you want it to be efficient. Be sure to add an index on the counter cache field.

Comment: @KyleBanker if you add this as an answer, I will gladly select it

Comment: Thank, @ChristianFazzini. Go ahead and award it to theTRON :)

Comment: @KyleBanker yeah sorry to snake that one away from you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure on the direction you were intending to sort in, so I included indexes for both - you should delete one, if you're not planning to use it, but this should do the trick for you:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :comments_count, :type => Integer, :default => 0
  index [[ :comments_count, Mongo::ASCENDING ]]
  index [[ :comments_count, Mongo::DESCENDING ]]
  has_many :comments

  before_save :update_comments_count

  protected
  def update_comments_count
    self.comments_count = self.comments.count
  end
end
```