# How would I grab only articles with comments that were created 20 minutes ago?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Using mongodb and mongoid. How would one grab all articles. Only articles with comments created 20 minutes ago?

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :article
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also do this, which should be more efficient:

```
articles = Article.where(:"comments.created_at".gt => 20.minutes.ago)
```

Comment: With a referenced relationship I don't think this will work. Although I cannot understand why this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
articles = Article.where(:_id.in => Comment.where(:created_at => 20.minutes.ago).map(&:article_id))
```